# How to add JWT Bearer Token to ALL requests to an API

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I'm in the process of trying to put together a small project which uses Asp.Net Core Identity, Identity Server 4 and a Web API project.

I've got my MVC project authenticating correctly with IdS4 from which I get a JWT which I can then add to the header of a request to my Web API project, this all works as expected.

The issue I have is how I'm actually adding the token to the `HttpClient`, basically I'm setting it up for every request which is obviously wrong otherwise I'd have seen other examples online, but I haven't been able to determine a good way to refactor this. I've read many articles and I have found very little information about this part of the flow, so I'm guessing it could be so simple that it's never detailed in guides, but I still don't know!

Here is an example MVC action that calls my API:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFromApi()
{
    var client = await GetHttpClient();
    string testUri = "https://localhost:44308/api/TestItems";
    var response = await client.GetAsync(testUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    GetFromApiViewModel vm = new GetFromApiViewModel()
    {
        Output = data
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

And here is the `GetHttpClient()` method which I call (currently residing in the same controller):

```
private async Task<HttpClient> GetHttpClient()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var expat = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at").Result;
    var dataExp = DateTime.Parse(expat, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
    if ((dataExp - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes < 10)
    {
         //SNIP GETTING A NEW TOKEN IF ITS ABOUT TO EXPIRE
    }

    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    return client;
}
```

My `StartUp` classes are pretty standard from what I gather, but if they could be useful, then I'll add them in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I've read many articles and I have found very little information about this part of the flow, so I'm guessing it could be so simple that it's never detailed in guides, but I still don't know!

The problem is that the docs are really spread all over, so it's hard to get a big picture of all the best practices. I'm planning a blog series on "Modern HTTP API Clients" that will collect all these best practices.

First, I [recommend you use `HttpClientFactory` rather than new-ing up an `HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net-core).

Next, adding an authorization header is IMO best done by hooking into the `HttpClient`'s pipeline of message handlers. A basic bearer-token authentication helper could look like this:

```
public sealed class BackendApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public BackendApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var expat = await _accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
        var dataExp = DateTime.Parse(expat, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
        if ((dataExp - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes < 10)
        {
             //SNIP GETTING A NEW TOKEN IF ITS ABOUT TO EXPIRE
        }

        var token = await _accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        // Use the token to make the call.
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This can be hooked up via DI:

```
services.AddTransient<BackendApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<MyController>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((provider, c) => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44308/api"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BackendApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler>();
```

Then you can inject an `HttpClient` into your `MyController`, and it will magically use the auth tokens:

```
// _client is an HttpClient, initialized in the constructor
string testUri = "TestItems";
var response = await _client.GetAsync(testUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

GetFromApiViewModel vm = new GetFromApiViewModel()
{
    Output = data
};
return View(vm);
```

This pattern seems complex at first, but it separates the "how do I call this API" logic from "what is this action doing" logic. And it's easier to extend with retries / circuit breakers / etc, via Polly.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it was exactly what I needed. Once I created the `HttpClientFactory` and managed to inject that into my Api class and the `BackendApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler` itself everything worked smoothly. I'll definitely look out for your blog post on this subject as I'm sure it'll answer many of my other questions of the subject!

Comment: did you ever made that  blog post?

Comment: @Fredou: No. We moved earlier this year and are just now moving again. Probably in 2022...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpRequestMessage`

```
// Create this instance once on stratup 
// (preferably you want to keep an instance per base url to avoid waiting for socket fin)
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Then create an instance of `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
  HttpMethod.Get, 
  "https://localhost:44308/api/TestItems");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "ey..");
await client.SendAsync(request);
```